# CKEditor 'Send it to the server' button is invisible

Tags: ckeditor

Experiencing strange behaviour with CKEditor. I have everything set up and I can upload images just fine. But the only problem I have is that I cannot see the 'Send it to the server' button in the upload form. I know it's there because if I hover over the area it's supposed to be on,  the alternative information reads 'Send it to the server'. Furthermore if I press the area, it will upload the photo:

[image]

I haven't edited any CSS files or tampered with the code except to include the upload script.

The `image.js` file reads:

```
{
    id: 'Upload',
    filebrowser: 'uploadButton',
    label: editor.lang.image.upload,
    elements: [
        {
        type: 'file',
        id: 'upload',
        label: editor.lang.image.btnUpload,
        style: 'height:40px',
        size: 38
    },
        {
        type: 'fileButton',
        id: 'uploadButton',
        filebrowser: 'info:txtUrl',
        label: editor.lang.image.btnUpload,
        'for': [ 'Upload', 'upload' ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The file input shows but not the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a custom skin I was using that didn't contain all the necessary classes.